# Turtlebot 3dSensor.Launch cannot find kinect as if it is not plugged in?

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I recently upgraded my Turtlebot from groovy to hydro, and am now trying to subscribe to the kinect data.  However, when I launch the 3dsensor.launch startup file, I get the following error:

No devices connected ... waiting for devices to be connected.

Everything else works fine, except that the Turtlebot cannot seem to find the kinect, despite the fact that the kinect is definitely plugged in.  Anyone know what the problem could be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149926/turtlebot-3dsensor.launch-cannot-find-kinect-as-if-it-is-not-plugged-in?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-07**:
@randylewis7: Could you check next items?

1. You plug your kinect to USB 2.0 on turtlebot PC.
2. There are two yaml file (depth_*****.yaml, rgb_*****.yaml) in ~/.ros/camera_info.

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-04-14**:
I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're asking. about the yaml files.  THe kinect is plugged in correctly but I can't find any directory called .ros/camera_info

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-14**:
@randylewis7: Do you put the command `cd ~/.ros` and  `ls`  on a terminal? If you can't see the directory  `camera_info` , I think you can do a calibration for kinect. Did you receive some message except for `No devices connected ...` ?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-14**:
I can check if I receive any messges in case that there is not camera_info. That means removing my camera_info folder. So I will do that if you wait for me.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-14**:
@randylewis7: I'm sorry. I checked that, [WARN] happens ,but the error didn't happens. I could look at a image on Rviz. I guess that you miss installing. I have experienced the error at the early version of groovy. When I reinstall ROS, I also reinstall Ubuntu OS. I like Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I had a similar problem after updating Ubuntu (13.04) in my PC.
I'm not sure what happened, but I had to reinstall the kinect driver:

I download this:
https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect

And in the "Bin" folder, I extract "SensorKinect093-Bin-Linux-x64-v5.1.2.1" and install it (by running the install.sh)

I hope that could work for you as well!

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Hdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5773/carlos-hdz/) with karma: 103 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-04-14**:
I tried this but it didn't seem to affect the error at all.

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-04-14**:
The only thing I've done that affected the error so far was to reinstall hydro on both the turtlebot and the workstation computer, which changed the error in that when running 3dsensor.launch, it waits till the end to say no devices are connected, rather than saying it every so often while launching other processes and then at the end.

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-04-14**:
Could incompatible versions of ROS be the problem, or do you think it's something else?